# Append HTML input with value="' + variable + '" is not giving me the correct value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mysql

I got a table (which gets created with PHP (data from mySQL)) that look like this:

```
<table class="data-table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="databasecontent">maybe some values</td>
      <td class="databasecontent">maybe empty</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="databasecontent">another row</td>
      <td class="databasecontent"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Then I got a list, which I want the content to append to:

```
<ul class="plannerlist" id="plannerlist2">
</ul>
```

(I got 6 `<ul>` in total with `id="plannerlist1, 2, ..."`).
So I want the text from `.databasecontent:nth-child(1)` to append to `ul#plannerlist1` with this JS:

```
var database1 = $("td.databasecontent:nth-child(1)").text;
$("ul#plannerlist1:visible").append('<input type="text" readonly value="' + database1 + '">');

var database2 = $("td.databasecontent:nth-child(2)").text;
$("ul#plannerlist2:visible").append('<input type="text" readonly value="' + database2 + '">');

and so on...
```

I think that jQuery should work but it's just giving me an input with the value:

```
function (a){return S(this,function(a){return void 0===a?r.text(this):this.empty().each(function(){1!==this.nodeType&&11!==this.nodeType&&9!==this.nodeType||(this.textContent=a)})},null,a,arguments.length)}
```

Whats the problem with my code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `.text()` instead of using `.text` and it will work perfectly if nothing wrong you have done.

Comment: If it helped you please accept the answer and upvote it for helping others.

Comment: @TobiasGlaus It's not funny, what the answer lack to explain is that `text` is a method from the `jQuery` api and as methods are functions they need to run in order to return anything.

Comment: No, it's not funny at all. What I wanted to say is that I sometimes search waaay to deeply. And then just like a `>`  `}` or `()` is missing. I knew that the jQuery `.text()` method needs these brackets.

Answer (score 0):

By using `var database2 = $("td.databasecontent:nth-child(2)").text;` you return function `text` itself, not the result of it. Try `var database2 = $("td.databasecontent:nth-child(2)").text();`.